# I want to resize the JTable column width

Tags: java, swing

I want to resize the column width according to content that is being retrieved from the database.
I have tried using TableCellRenderer but it does nothing
Please Help !!

[image]

Comment: can you try this  `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`!

Comment: i have tried this. It doesn't work